# How to clean cache in heroku after installing dependencies?

Tags: node.js, heroku, heroku-cli

Topic : Heroku
Problem : After installing my node js application in heroku, I made some changes in package.json. Now, when I am trying to push changes again, new dependencies are not getting installed. Heroku is picking the dependencies from cache.

How to disable cache in heroku ?

Comment: Have you tried creating a `npm-shrinkwrap.json`? If you installed new dependencies and [shrinkwrap](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap) your project then npm will install everything in the shrinkwrap using the exact versions

Comment: Hmm.  I've never found heroku not update my package.jsom dependencies on a deploy.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Thanks all for responding.

After much googling and spending time on my issue, I was able to solve my problem.
I thought it would be better to post an answer if anyone faces the similar dilemma.

Below is the documentation, where I found my answer https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support

1. By default, in heroku production is set to true. That's why only dependencies get installed. ( & skips devDependencies )

   ```
   heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
   ```

Set production to false, to force heroku to install all packages.

```
** Only do this if doing development.
```

2. Heroku, by default, caches all the dependencies, so that the deployment is faster.

   ```
   heroku config:set NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false

   $ git commit -am 'disable node_modules cache' --allow-empty

   $ git push heroku master

   ** Preferable only if new dependencies are added in package.json
   ```