# Hi, Can't figure out why heroku can't find mongoose module. Any idea?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, mongoose

I Can't figure out why heroku  can't find mongoose module

[image]

Comment: fixed the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45064655/how-to-clean-cache-in-heroku-after-installing-dependencies/45073405#45073405

Answer (score 0):

It's because `mongoose` is set as a `devDependency`. Heroku usually deploys things in `production` mode, which means development dependencies are not installed. You should set `mongoose` as a regular `dependency` in your `package.json`.

(You could also tell Heroku to run in `development` mode, but that's probably not the right solution since you almost certainly want mongoose to be available in production.)

Answer (score 0):

It's because mongoose is listed on `devDependencies` of your package.json.

By default Heroku will strip out the modules declared under `devDependencies` before deploying the application.

One way to solve this is move mongoose to `dependencies` on package.json. Other way is set NODE_ENV environment variable to other value than `production` that is the default, so Heroku will mantain the modules on `devDependencies`.